# How to use ActiveX/COM from ColdFusion?

Tags: com, coldfusion, activex

Is it possible to use an ActiveX/COM object from ColdFusion?  If so, where's the documentation or samples for it?

(non ColdFusion programmer, asking on behalf of a ColdFusion programmer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see: [Integrating COM and CORBA Objects in CFML Applications](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/cfobject_01.html#1100380)

If you're worried about COM object performance, use .NET based CFML Engine like [BlueDragon for the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://www.newatlanta.com/products/bluedragon/product_info/overview.cfm)

Answer (score 3):

You can call both COM objects and .Net assemblies natively in ColdFusion both with excellent performance.  Check out the following in the cf docs:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/cfobject_01.html
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=dotNet_01.html

Examples are included in the docs.